# How to rewrite this simple component tree to take advantage of React.memo?

Tags: reactjs

In the following [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-driscoll-9fsnm?file=/src/App.js) we have a `<Child />` component that either renders within a `<div />` or not, depending on state.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";

const Child = memo(
  ({ n }) => {
    console.log("Re-rendered child");
    return <span>Child {n}</span>;
  },
  () => true
);

export default function App() {
  const [shouldWrapChildComponent, setShouldWrapChildComponent] = useState(
    false
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setShouldWrapChildComponent(
            (shouldWrapChildComponent) => !shouldWrapChildComponent
          )
        }
      >
        Toggle Wrapper
      </button>

      <br />

      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n) => {
        return shouldWrapChildComponent ? (
          <div>
            <Child n={n} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Child n={n} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the `<Child />` component is using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to prevent re-renders.

However, re-renders are not prevented when the component tree changes (and this makes sense). If `shouldWrapChildComponent` is `true`, then  `<Child />` will render inside of a `<div />`, and otherwise `<Child />` will render where `<div />` used to render. This is what I mean by "the component tree changes".

Is there a way to rewrite the components such that the component tree *does not change*, and therefore can take advantage of React.memo? Or, given that we'll always need conditionally wrap the `<Child />` component, is there no way to have React preserve the rendered output of `<Child />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, re-renders are not prevented when the component tree changes (and this makes sense). If shouldWrapChildComponent is true, then  will render inside of a , and otherwise  will render where  used to render. This is what I mean by "the component tree changes"

Let's talk about the above quotation, let's do a small change and remove the `div` element:

```
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n) => {
        return shouldWrapChildComponent ? (
          <Child n={n} />
        ) : (
          <Child n={n} />
        );
      })
}
```

The result is: your `Child` component will re-render only 6 times even after toggling with the button. You can put a console.log() on the `App` component and check the console, the toggle button will cause a re-render for your whole `App` but the `Child` component will not re-render anymore.

So, the **memorization** is working **properly** and prevents the child component from extra re-render.

But the problem appeared when you wrap your `Child` component with another element ( here with `div`), why?

To check this behavior, I separate the main part from the return method by creating a `resultArray` variable just to log the `resultArray` before rendering.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";

const Child = memo(
  ({ n }) => {
    console.log("Re-rendered child");
    return <span>Child {n}</span>;
  },
  () => true
);

export default function App() {
  const [shouldWrapChildComponent, setShouldWrapChildComponent] = useState(
    false
  );

  const resultArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n) => {
        return shouldWrapChildComponent ? (
          <div>
            <Child n={n} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Child n={n} />
        );
      })

  console.log(`When shouldWrapChildComponent is ${shouldWrapChildComponent} the result array is: `, resultArray);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setShouldWrapChildComponent(
            (shouldWrapChildComponent) => !shouldWrapChildComponent
          )
        }
      >
        Toggle Wrapper
      </button>
      <br />
      {resultArray}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `resultArray` when `shouldWrapChildComponent` is **false**:

```
>(6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

>0: Object
  type: "div"  // pay attention here
  key: null
  ref: null
  >props: Object
     n: 0         // ----> passing n via props to Child
  _owner: FiberNode
  _store: Object
>1: Object
>2: Object
>3: Object
>4: Object
>5: Object
```

The `resultArray` when `shouldWrapChildComponent` is **true**:

```
>(6) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

>0: Object
  type: null    // pay attention here
  key: null
  ref: null
  >props: Object     // -----> passing a object instead of Child
    >children: Object
      >type: Object
        >type:   ƒ _c() {}
        >compare: f () {}
  _owner: FiberNode
  _store: Object
>1: Object
>2: Object
>3: Object
>4: Object
>5: Object
```

As you can see, the result is totally different, so react will trigger a re-render every time to draw the new elements in DOM.

##### React Reconciliation Algorithm

> When diffing two trees, React first compares the two root elements. The behavior is different depending on the types of the root elements.

So, as the element `type` gets changed, the `Reconciliation` algorithm flagged it and tried to re-rendered it, this re-render is like the first render on your component before the component did mount (and cause extra re-render with your Child element).

More on React official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

##### As a simplest solution

There are many solutions to avoid this extra re-rendering, but as a simple solution you can change the main part as below:

```
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((n) => {
        return shouldWrapChildComponent ? (
          <div>
            <Child n={n} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div style={{display: "inline"}}>
            <Child n={n} />
          </div>
        );
      })
}
```